# Why is java 8 unable to identify the integer array (y) passed to this method?

Tags: java, cannot-find-symbol

```
public class Solution {
    public static int solution(int[] x, int[] y) {

        // for every value in x
        for (int v : x){
            // check if value exists in y
            boolean i = y.contains(v);
            // if indicator returns false the value is returned
            if (i == false){
                int r = v;
            }

        }
```

> Solution.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
>              boolean i = y.contains(v);
>                           ^
>    symbol:   method contains(int)
>    location: variable y of type int[]

Comment: Arrays don't have a contains method.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comment, arrays in java don't have `contains()` method. But if the arrays x and y are already sorted, how about using `Arrays.binarySearch(y,v)` ? If the value v is present, you would get the index at which v is present in array y. Otherwise you would get negative value

Comment: You are right. I corrected the answer. Thanks for pointing that out.